# Why do people like using evolution computing techniques like GA on multi-objective optimisation?

Tags: reference-request, optimization, ne.neural-evol

I am new to the field of multi-objective optimisation and I try to find some books to read on this topic.

Yet when I search around my library I found there are many books on using evolution computing technique like GA on multi-objective optimisation.

Why is there such a strong link between this the problem and this technique?

p.s. I saw some books talk about reducing the problem into single objective optimisation and make use of conventional optimisation techniques but its always a small chapter, any suggesting materials on this direction?